# Someone has suffered or can test FreeImage_ConvertToXXX issues?

Tags: c++, image-conversion, freeimage, bit-depth

I was thinking it was my fault but making a much more simplier code it still fails:

```
FIBITMAP* infloat = FreeImage_ConvertToRGBF(bitmap);
FreeImage_Save(fifpng, bitmap, "D:\\orig.png", 0); //THIS WORKS OK
FreeImage_Save(fifexr, infloat, "D:\\justTest.exr", 0); //THIS WORKS OK

FIBITMAP *pImage = FreeImage_ConvertTo24Bits(infloat);
if (pImage == NULL)
    printf("CONVERSION FAILED\n");
```

It failed in FreeImage_ConvertTo24Bits and FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits but I cannot imagine why since infloat seems to be ok and bitmap is ok too.

Notice that if I make:
    FIBITMAP *pImage = FreeImage_ConvertTo24Bits(bitmap);

it works ok too.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: What is the failure that you are getting?

Comment: Sorry I forget to specify it: pImage is NULL